# Data: to clean or not to clean

Tags: data, portfolio-management, risk-management

From risk management point of view using cleaned data (excluding or modifying extreme/outlier observations) would give less conservative measure as compared to real-world raw data. So they are more reluctant to base their conclusions on facts that are really observed.

However, portfolio managers would want to use cleaned data in order to get a more `robust and stable estimation of the distribution generating the large majority of the return data`.

As a result when they optimize their portfolio using some sort of risk measure (st.dev, CVaR, etc.) these two parties will get totally different picture.

Should having two different approaches be allowed in the first place? If yes, then how conflict situations (e.g. exceeding risk budgets) can be solved? In what cases do you think data cleaning is permissible? Sort of philosophical questions, but would love to know your thoughts.

**Update**

Thank you all for the answers.

@will, if data is error-free but has some outliers/extreme values, as per the below it seems to be fine to somehow reduce their impact in portfolio optimization:

[Application of robust statistics to asset allocation models](https://www.ine.pt/revstat/pdf/rs070106.pdf)

> Many strategies for asset allocation involve the computation of the
>   expected value and the covariance matrix of the returns of financial
>   instruments. How much of each instrument to own is determined by an
>   attempt to minimize risk — the variance of linear combinations of
>   investments in these financial assets — subject to various constraints
>   such as a given level of return, concentration limits, etc. The
>   covariance matrix contains many parameters to estimate and two main
>   problems arise. **First, the data will very likely have outliers that
>   will seriously affect the covariance matrix.** Second, with so many
>   parameters to estimate, a large number of return observations are
>   required and the nature of markets may change substantially over such
>   a long period. In this paper we discuss using **robust covariance
>   procedures, FAST-MCD, Iterated Bivariate Winsorization and Fast 2-D
>   Winsorization, to address the first problem** and penalization methods
>   for the second. When back-tested on market data, these methods are
>   shown to be effective in improving portfolio performance. **Robust asset
>   allocation methods have great potential to improve risk-adjusted
>   portfolio returns and therefore deserve further exploration in
>   investment management research**.

[Robust Portfolio Construction](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-0-387-77439-8_11) (can't find the full version)

> Outliers in asset returns factors are a frequently occurring
>   phenomenon across all asset classes and can have an adverse influence
>   on the performance of mean–variance optimized (MVO) portfolios. This
>   occurs by virtue of the unbounded influence that outliers can have on
>   the mean returns and covariance matrix estimates (alternatively,
>   correlations and variances estimates) that are inputs are optimizer
>   inputs. **A possible solution to the problem of such outlier sensitivity
>   of MVO is to use robust estimates of mean returns and covariance
>   matrices in place of the classical estimates of these quantities
>   thereby providing robust MVO portfolios. We show that the differences
>   occurring between classical and robust estimates for these portfolios
>   are such as to be of considerable concern to a portfolio manager. It
>   turns out that robust distances based on a robust covariance matrix
>   can provide reliable identification of multidimensional outliers in
>   both portfolio returns and the exposures matrix of a fundamental
>   factor model, something that is not possible with one-dimensional
>   Winsorization.** Multidimensional visualization combined with clustering
>   methods is also useful for returns outlier identification. The
>   question of using robust and classical MVO vs. optimization-based
>   fat-tailed skewed distribution fits and downside risk measure is
>   briefly discussed. Some other applications of robust methods in
>   portfolio management are described, and we point out some future
>   research that is needed on the topic.

[Outliers and Portfolio Optimization](http://www.master272.com/finance/AQPM/2004_Charles.pdf)

> In this paper we study the impact of outliers on global minimum
>   variance portfolios. From the method developed by Gomez and Maravall
>   (1997, 2000), we detect and correct outliers in Cac40 French index and
>   in three French stocks included in it. It appears that all financial
>   data present outliers, some of them may be explained by economic and
>   financial events. We calculate the conditional volatility forecast for
>   60, 120 and 180 business days, using GARCH (1,1) model with 440
>   observations. As suggested by Franses and Ghijsels (1999), we show
>   that outliers disturb the volatility estimates. Indeed, it seems
>   better to correct outliers before forecasting volatility than used
>   unadjusted series. To evaluate the forecast error, we compute the MSPE
>   and the MAPE. **Finally, we examine the impact of outliers on the
>   global variance minimum portfolio structure. The weights of each
>   stocks are significantly different if the series are beforehand
>   ajusted or not. Moreover, portfolio evaluation is better for adjusted
>   data rather than for unadjusted data. Consequently, it seems important
>   to take into account outliers in portfolio optimisation because they
>   affect portfolio variance, weights of portfolio and portfolio
>   evaluation.**

There are some other resources, but I do not have full access. Also, I clearly recall where practitioners mentioned taking care of outliers in portfolio construction. Obviously, they were clear and open about their "manipulations" (e.g. threw away 2-3 observations from 2007-08 period). That is why I was wondering if this approach has some merits.

@noob2 - I was looking at `clean.boudt` as a potential solution for outlier detection and data cleaning.

Any further thoughts on this?

Comment: What do you mean by "cleaned data"?

Comment: throwing away or decreasing the magnitude of outlier/extreme observations.

Comment: then you should reformulate the question as this is not clear at all. Would this mean that e.g. an equity return after the Brexit vote, the French or US presidential elections should be discarded? VaR without large returns? short answer: you need these.

Comment: When you "clean" your data, it should never be about removing things which actually happened because they break your algos, that means your algos are wrong. It should be about removing mistakes, correcting for corporate actions, and removing made up data.

Comment: What Will said.  Also, you might consider a mixed distribution - one for the distribution you are trying to the model that does not contain outliers - and one for the actual outliers - then you will need to fit a distribution that handles this blend well.

Comment: As a portfolio/fund manager I can tell you directly that your second paragraph is completely false.  The type of data you are referring to is not "cleaned", it's manipulated for a goal seeking purpose.  @will comment is 100% accurate.

Comment: @amdopt completely agree on the "manipulation" point - if you're doing this internally to make your algos work, then you're basically saying "i am right, the data is wrong", and making an executive decision that you know better than reality. If you have to get yout work validated, they will spot something this obvious (one you certainly hope), and you'll have no way of justifying it.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I updated/modified the OP with some references.

Comment: There are certain things that people do with their data, where the justification of doing it is argued - i.e. say we take data from the middle of some financial crisis, and we remove some of the particularly awful days - we might want to do this and try to argue that the days we removed are outside of the sample, because the regime has changed, and we just want to get data which behaves like the market, excluding this behaviour because it belongs in a different regime. Personally, i disagree with this approach, and if you're arguing the regime has changed, why use the data in the first place?

Comment: That is why I am trying to understand why do I have believe in robust portfolio construction (which doesn't care about tail risk) instead of classical approach. As you can see there seems to be extensive research that backs this. In practice there may well be the cases where portfolio managers lean towards stable estimation. What I am chasing is how risks can be controlled in such cases?

Answer (score 1):

To expand upon what others have said in the comments especially @will's. Data "cleansing" is not just about finding outliers or extreme values or manipulating data.

The examples below are fairly common scenarios from even the largest data vendors that must also be considered for historical or ongoing analysis. All of these issues below can throw an entire model off.

- Vendor provides incorrect values on a stock price or volume.

  - Ex: The adjusted close not taking into account splits or dividends.
- Provides a incorrect contract specifications for a corporate bond or swap.

  - EX: The wrong coupon frequency, currency code, exc..
- Historical intra-day quotes with incorrect time stamps.
- An exchange stops accepting orders but still sends bid/ask quotes mid market.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Let's assume - hypothetically - that the data are perfectly fine and have no errors. The detected outliers are real and observed in the market. My PM happens to be using a portfolio construction/analytics software that has a feature that takes care of outliers (winsorization or whatever). She goes ahead and constructs a portfolio using this method as well as the classical method, which accepts data as they are. Goes on to backtesting and reverts back with similar findings as in the existing research (some mentioned in the OP). How should I set my risk limits?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winsorizing